# How to auto shutdown and startup vm's in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Microsoft added the feature to auto-shutdown vm's from the "Virtual Machine" blade (you navigate over to the VM, select "Auto-Shutdown from left-nav, specify the time and you are set). This works fine. However, there is no such option to auto-startup vm's. Reason I bring this up is because Google (GCP) provides that option.

Now, I am aware there are other more complicated ways to achieve this in Azure (via runbooks and functions) ; I have tried them and not liked them at all.

Checking to see if others achieve this on your Azure Cloud or whether you are aware of Microsoft's plan to add this feature anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Many organizations use auto-start/auto-shutdown policy on azure vms based on their internal working. For example, Dev/UAT environment doesn't require VMs to be running all the time and they prefer to manage VMs to keep them power on during office hours or off-time during weekends.

In past, I have used below reference from Microsoft to create policy for multiple clusters vms which permit to add schedule of startup and shutdown on particular time/date with reoccurance.
Please note that don't create multiple policy for each VMs where it create conflict. So you need to carefully design and implement policy in Azure so that there's no conflict between one or more policies.

I have this links helps you.

Auto-shutdown Policy =>    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-auto-shutdown

Auto-start policy =>    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-auto-startup-vm

Comment: This is only for DevTest labs.